# python's re: replace regex to regex

Tags: python, regex

I have to replace text with text which was found. Smth like this:

```
regex = u'barbar'
oldstring = u'BarBaR barbarian BarbaRONt'
pattern = re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
newstring = pattern.sub(.....)
print(newstring) # And here is what I want to see
>>> u'TEXT1BarBaRTEXT2 TEXT1barbarTEXT2ian TEXT1BarbaRTEXT2ONt'
```

So I want to receive my original text, where each word that matches 'barbar' (with ignored case) will be surrounded by two words, **TEXT1** and **TEXT2**. Return value must be a unicode string.
How can I realize it? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use capturing group for that:

```
regex = u'(barbar)'
...
pattern.sub('TEXT1\\1TEXT2', oldstring)
# => u'TEXT1BarBaRTEXT2 TEXT1barbarTEXT2ian TEXT1BarbaRTEXT2ONt'
```

Taking `barbar` into parenthesis makes regexp to capture every part of the string that matches this part of the regexp into a group. As it's the first (and the only one) capturing group you can refer to it as `\1` anywhere in the replacement string or in the regexp itself.

For more explanation see `(...)` and `\number` sections in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Btw, if you don't like escaping of the slash before group number you can use raw string instead:

```
pattern.sub(r'TEXT1\1TEXT2', oldstring)
```